# script: "git rev-parse ${latestTag}^{commit}" fails in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Below line in Jenkinsfile

`latestTagSHA1 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse ${latestTag}^{commit}")`

results in `script.sh: ^{commit}: not found` error.

Is there a way to escape `^{commit}` part?

I tried to use `^\{commit\}` to no avail.

It's important to note that i want to actually run command

`git rev-parse ${latestTag}^{commit}`, for example `git rev-parse 2.0.0^{commit}` where `latestTag` equals `2.0.0`.

This command returns SHA1 of git tag. For example, for existing tagged commit `850d25580a894befbce6d922bee954c7669cf70c` with tag `1.0` below command will return the `SHA1` of the tag:

```
git rev-parse 1.0^{commit}
850d25580a894befbce6d922bee954c7669cf70c
```

added full `Jenkinsfile` using the failing line:

```
pipeline {
    agent  {
        node {
            label 'some_label'
            customWorkspace "workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${params.PROJECT}/${params.REPO_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/"
        }
    }

    parameters {
        string defaultValue: "${REPO_NAME}", name: 'REPO_NAME', trim: true
        string defaultValue: "${PROJECT}", name: 'PROJECT', trim: true
        string defaultValue: "${SRC_BRANCH_NAME}", name: 'SRC_BRANCH_NAME', trim: true
        string defaultValue: "${PR_MERGER_EMAIL}", name: 'PR_MERGER_EMAIL', trim: true
        string defaultValue: "${SHA1}", name: 'SHA1', trim: true
    }
    options {
        lock resource: "${params.REPO_NAME}" // lock on repo to avoid concurrent releases on the same repo
    }

    stages {
        stage("package") {
            steps {
                dir("/tmp/${params.PROJECT}/${params.REPO_NAME}") {                    
                    checkout(
                        [
                            $class: 'GitSCM',
                            branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']],
                            extensions: [
                                            [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "master"]
                                        ],
                            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                                    url: env.GIT_URL, credentialsId: "smth"
                                ]]
                        ]
                    )
                    script {                    
                        sh "cd /tmp/${params.PROJECT}/${params.REPO_NAME}"                    
                        latestTag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`")
                        latestTagSHA1 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse ${latestTag}^{commit}")
                        latestSHA1Timestamp = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git show -s  --format='%ct' ${latestTagSHA1}")
                        currentCommitSHA1Timestamp = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git show -s  --format='%ct' ${params.SHA1}")
                        if (latestSHA1Timestamp > currentCommitSHA1Timestamp) {
                            currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                            error('some')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please paste entire code or the code where you are trying to get ${latestTag}^{commit} etc so we can understand the issue.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar added `Jenkinsfile`

Comment: it shouldn't return anything, it's git command syntax `git rev-parse 2.0.0^{commit}`

Comment: No, it's not: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @MaratC did you read the question? i provided an example

Comment: Your example doesn't work on my machine for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to escape anything in line that throws the error. The problem is that the `sh` step returns an output with a trailing newline.

> **returnStdout** (optional)
>
> If checked, standard output from the task is returned as the step value as a `String`, rather than being printed to the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the log.) You will often want to call `.trim()` on the result to strip off a trailing newline.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script</sup>

That is why what Jenkins is trying to execute in your case is:

```
git rev-parse 1.0.0
^{commit}
```

instead of

```
git rev-parse 1.0.0^{commit}
```

The solution to this problem is simple: when you return the output of the `sh` step, call `trim()` in the end to remove a trailing newline.

```
latestTag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`").trim()
```

Keep in mind that you will have to trim the output of all variables that are later use as a part of the next command.

Comment: thanks, that helped

Answer (score -1):

You can try: "git rev-parse ${latestTag}"^${commit}""

You need to add the $ for all variables you want to call

Comment: no, that's not what i want, I edited the question.